# Can we setup salesforce sso or Idp login within Iframe to login to a external site

Tags: apex, connected-apps, single-sign-on, authentication, iframe

I have an Iframe in salesforce which loads an external site that supports salesforce sso, currently I'm redirecting the user to the external site auth0 login page and once they login I redirect them to Iframe and load the application, is there a way I can enable the user to login directly when they load the Iframe using sso or Idp, so they don't have to login again with the credentials

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is the [Canvas API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm). You will need to modify your external app to support this authentication model. This API not only authenticates the external app automatically, but it also allows two-way communication between the parent Salesforce window and the framed external app. The documentation above goes in to more detail. A less secure model allows you to use pass in the session ID directly via `{!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_xxx}` and `{!$Api.Session_ID}`. Your external app can receive these as parameters to use the API directly. See the [`$Api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm) documentation. No matter how you look at it, SSO/IdP solutions are not the correct solution to your problem.